# How to keep distinctness until specific condition is true on EPL ESPER

Tags: esper, epl, complex-event-processing

I have two event types (A and B). I would like to write a pattern which detects every *B* event which comes after *A* event with the same id: `every A -> B (A.id = B.id)`. However, it should be distinct ids. In other words, the pattern should ignore all *A* events with the same id after the first one until the above expression is true, means *B* event with the same id comes.

For example, Assume this is an event stream:

`1. A (id: 1); 2. A(id: 2); 3. A (id: 3); 4. A(id: 1); 5. A (id: 2); 6. B (id: 1); 7. B (id: 2); 8. A (id: 1); 9. B(id: 3); 10. A (id: 1); 11. B (id: 1)`

The pattern should ignore event No4 as it has the same id with event No1. When the event No6 comes, the pattern should match `1. A (id: 1) -> 6. B (id: 1)`.  Then, the pattern should allow new *A* event with id=1. So event No8 should not be ignored, but event No10 should be ignored. When event No11 comes, the pattern should match again `8. A(id: 1) -> 11. B(id: 1)`.

Besides, event No2 should match with event No7 and event No3 should match event No9.

I have tried to use `EVERY-DISTINCT(A.id) A -> B (A.id=B.id)`, but it ignores all *A* events with the same id after the first one. Then I tried `EVERY (A -> B (A.id = B.id))`, but it didn't work either as it ignores all *A* events regardless of id until *B* event with the same id comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `every A -> B (A.id = B.id)` statement within `PATTERN` statement and add additionally add `@SuppressOverlappingMatches` right after `PATTERN` keyword.

Complete statement will be something like this:

```
SELECT b.id FROM PATTERN @SuppressOverlappingMatches [every a=A -> b=B (a.id = b.id)]
```

Reference: http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html/event_patterns.html#patterns-howto-suppress